# Does performing contains on a set make lazy map redundant?

Tags: ios, swift

Suppose I have the following

```
let ids = mySet.lazy.map { $0.id }
ids.contains(...)
```

Does the `.contains()` function make `lazy` redundant? I'm assuming it has to perform `map` on the whole of `mySet` to be able to perform `contains()`?
Or am I wrong?

Comment: Note that `map` retunes an `array`. You should use `contains` on your `set` instead `if mySet.contains(whatever) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong.

Adding `.lazy` causes map to return a `LazyMapSequence` instead of an `Array`.  When you call `.contains` on this `LazyMapSequence`, it will execute the mapping operation on each element as `.contains` checks it.

Imagine your set has 100 items.  `.contains` quits as soon as it finds the item you are searching for, so if you get lucky and the first item in your `Set` satisfies `.contains`, then only that item will be `.map`ped and `.contains` will immediately return `true`.

Note that `Set`s are unordered, so the order it is searched is unspecified.

Try this in a Playground:

```
struct Person : Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

let mySet = Set([Person(id: 1, name: "Joe"),
                 Person(id: 2, name: "Abhijit"),
                 Person(id: 3, name: "Fred")])

let ids = mySet.lazy.map { (person) -> Int in print("mapped \(person)"); return person.id }
print(ids.contains(1))
```

Observe the output.  When I tried it I got:

> ```
> mapped Person(id: 1, name: "Joe")
> true
> ```

Then remove `.lazy` and run it again.  I got:

> ```
> mapped Person(id: 1, name: "Joe")
> mapped Person(id: 3, name: "Fred")
> mapped Person(id: 2, name: "Abhijit")
> true
> ```

So `.lazy` eliminates the need to run `.map` on every item.  If `.contains` finds what it is looking for, then it is unnecessary to run `.map` on every item.

Note: If the `Set` does not contain the item you are searching for, then every item will be visited and `.map`ped before `.contains` can return `false`.

---

> Now what if contains is called multiple
> times? Will that have to start from an “unmapped” sequence again? Or
> will it have stored the previously mapped values somewhere?

The second effect of `lazy` is that no storage is used to hold the intermediate mapped values. So calling `contains` multiple times will execute the mapping operation again for each set value that is accessed.

Comment: Great answer. Now what if contains is called multiple times? Will that have to start from an “unmapped” sequence again? Or will it have stored the previously mapped values somewhere?

Comment: Great follow up question. I updated the answer.